# CSV to array and foreach through each row

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a CSV that has multiple rows within it. I am trying to get my code to foreach through each row but it seems to be stopping after the first row.

The script is updating Magento prices on multiple products but which have the same starting numbers for the SKU before the "_" you can see this is the code.

I think this is where it might be getting stuck as the array's are not flat or the foreach is getting stuck, I'm not sure.

```
 $rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file('price/price-update.csv'));
        $header = array_shift($rows);
        //var_dump($rows);
        $csv = array();

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            $productcode = $csv[0]['Product Code'];
            $newprice = $csv[0]['New Price'];
            $specialprice = $csv[0]['Special Price'];
            $status = $csv[0]['Status'];
            var_dump($productcode);

            for ( $i = 1; $i < 15; $i++ ) {


                $magentoSku = $productcode."_0".$i;

                var_dump($magentoSku);
                // get magento product based on sku above
                $product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$magentoSku);
                //var_dump($product);

                if ( $product->getSku() == $magentoSku ) {

                    //sku match, update price
                    $product->setPrice($newprice); 
                    $product->setSpecialPrice($specialprice);
                    if ($status == "A") {
                        $product->setStatus(1); 
                    } else {
                        $product->setStatus(0); 
                    }    
                    $product->save();
                    //var_dump($product);

                } else {

                    echo "No Match";
                    // sku doesnt match, don't update anything, and continue looping

                }       
            }
        }
```

Output of $rows:

`array(2) { [0]=> array(15) { [0]=> string(7) "1234150" [1]=> string(9) "HEADBOARD" [2]=> string(8) "WING 6'0" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(6) "459.99" [5]=> string(7) "1121115" [6]=> string(6) "279.99" [7]=> string(7) "1130610" [8]=> string(1) "0" [9]=> string(1) "0" [10]=> string(1) "A" [11]=> string(1) "0" [12]=> string(1) "Y" [13]=> string(1) "C" [14]=> string(18) "Available to Order" } [1]=> array(15) { [0]=> string(7) "1234149" [1]=> string(9) "HEADBOARD" [2]=> string(8) "WING 6'0" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(6) "459.99" [5]=> string(7) "1121115" [6]=> string(6) "279.99" [7]=> string(7) "1130610" [8]=> string(1) "0" [9]=> string(1) "0" [10]=> string(1) "D" [11]=> string(1) "0" [12]=> string(1) "Y" [13]=> string(1) "C" [14]=> string(18) "Available to Order" } }`

Comment: What does an entry of your CSV file look like? Can you see your `var_dump($rows);` outputting correctly?

Comment: @crmpicco I have added this for you in the question

Comment: So your array has two elements - is that as you'd expect? Also, is this `$csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);` correct? Can you dump out `$csv` after you use array_combine and check that this is what you are looking for?

Comment: what are the total number of rows in your file? are they more than 2?

Comment: @Kalyan There will be a lot more rows, I am only using two for testing

Comment: If you remove your `for` loop (not foreach) in the question and your code it may help you to debug it, as it would seem that issue is before the `foreach`.

Comment: @crimpicco when I dump $csv it only gets the first row not the second

Comment: @crmpicco even with the for loop removed so it should just match sku it still only updates the first row

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have an error in your CSV file, open it with your favorite spreadsheet-editor and choose the delimiter and enclosure. If the table looks good then just open ist with
`Varien_File_Csv` Class

```
protected function _parseCSV($file)
    {
        $csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
        $csv->setDelimiter(',');
        $csv->setEnclosure('"');

        $data = $csv->getData($file);
        //$this->_headLine = array_shift($data);

        return $data;
    }
```

What you do with $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row); is to push a new array to the $csv, this might also make some trouble. I would advise you to use Mage::log() for each iteration and check how data looks. Its an easy problem, but you have the code...

Comment: There aren't any errors in CSV as the Expected number of rows are 2. And the dump from csv has 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for most part is correct, except for this part

```
//this should be assigned to a separate variable first
$csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
//because in second iteration, the data you require is in $csv[1]
//this will essentially fetch only the first productcode always for all rows.
$productcode = $csv[0]['Product Code'];
```

Here is the corrected piece of snippet

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // assign it to a var
    $csv_data = array_combine($header, $row);
    $productcode = $csv_data['Product Code'];
    $newprice = $csv_data['New Price'];
    $specialprice = $csv_data['Special Price'];
    $status = $csv_data['Status'];
    // stuff it into an array later
    $csv[] = $csv_data;
    var_dump($productcode);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have implemented your suggestion but it still seems to stop after the first row.

Comment: @KMW Could you please check if the first row in CSV has the field names?

Comment: Yes it does have them in the CSV as the first row, its as if it goes through the loop once and then stops